# Generating a Shadow under Xlib Window

Tags: linux, window, shadow, xlib, compiz

apparently the Window Manager (Compiz in my case) handles the drop shadow you see under all Xlib windows in Ubuntu, so communicating to the X Window system won't affect the default shadow generated on a window that I have created in my code. Therefore how do I communicate through my code with Compiz to assign a larger/smaller/different color shadow under the newly created window?

Edit: I'm using just c++ and the xlib library, not QT

Edit: The method of talking to the window manager is seeming increasingly complex the more I try, so anyone have any other suggestions? Maybe a second window behind the original with some sort of setup?

Comment: Read about [EVMH](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/EWMH) e.g. [the specs here](http://standards.freedesktop.org/wm-spec/wm-spec-1.5.html). Also better use an existing toolkit like e.g. [Qt](http://qt-project.org/) - life is really short to reinvent such *complex* things.

Comment: Thank you for directing me to that, I'll be sure to study it thoroughly. And in response to using QT, life is too short to create complex things without a true understanding.

Comment: I really mean that for (now mostly historical) various reasons, doing X11 at the Xlib level is really complex. And X11 is becoming obsolete (at least that is what people working on Wayland, Mir, etc... claim). You could use other toolkits [GTK](http://gtk.org/), [FOX](http://fox-toolkit.org/) etc...

Comment: It is extremely unlikely Compiz would allow you to control purely cosmetic parameters programmatically per window, thus letting you create non-uniform visual appearance (a very undesirable effect for most people) I would dare say its maintainers have more creative ways to waste their time, erm, important things on their agenda. (EWMH has nothing on window shadows).

Comment: @n.m. Yeah so I've found. In this case my new alternative idea is to make a second transparent, undecorated window behind the original, and display a shadow bitmap across it. any idea on how to make a window transparent?

Comment: Frankly, I think it would be a waste of time. Your WM should do decorations, not the application. If you don:t like how your WM does it, file a bug, or roll your own WM. Having said that, you might have luck if you ask this as a separate question.

Comment: wow that actually made a lot of sense. However, I've been pretty successful in my venture today, so I'll post up a how-to as an aswer when I'm done. Thank you both for your advice, really made me realize how different of a paradigm a linux gui and the x window system is.

Answer (score 1):

You need to write composite manager to have shadow/transparency and similar effects (I assume you are doing this to learn how it works under the hood. If you just need shadow - pretty much every comp manager have this option, read xcompmgr / compiz manuals)

Here is a very [good introduction](http://www.talisman.org/~erlkonig/misc/x11-composite-tutorial/) to Composite/Damage extensions. You need to redirect all toplevel windows and draw them manually on a special overlay window